# Selector multiple class in parent

Tags: jquery

Maybe it's a bit specific on my project but I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

For a job project I have a website who used a third part iframe where I can't edit the html. I need to add a click event on some part of this iframe **(example)**. 
The html coming from the iframe look like this :

```
<div class="a">
   <div class="b">
     <div class="c">
        <div class="c1">
           C1
        </div>
        <div class="c2">
           C2
        </div>
        <div class="c3">
           C3
        </div>
     </div
   </div
</div>
```

I need to add my event on the `c2` and `c3` but not on the `c1` div so I create a selector like this :  `$('.a .b .c .c2, .a .b .c .c3')`

It's work fine but in my case the class name are much longer (so my selector has like 100 character...) and the `.c2` and .`c3` class are used on other part of the project so I need to keep the `.a .b. .c` part.

Is this possible to do selector like this 
`$('.a .b .c (.c2 || .c3)')` ?

Or have you any idea ? Like stoping the selector on `.c` and detect the target class ? Is this really a better solution ?

Comment: `$(.a > .b > .c > .c2 , .a > .b > .c > .c3) ` should work

Comment: @CaptainPlanet My problem is having a too long selector and want to optimize it. $('.a .b .c .c2, .a .b .c .c3') work but in my case I have a c4 with class name much longer.

Comment: @CaptainPlanet That does not solve the OP's problem at all.

Comment: Is there a rule to which ones you select - you say "not c1 div" but is that because it's the first, ie "not the first div".  In which case would something like: `$(".a .b .c > :not(:first-child)")` work?

Comment: Are these `c`s created dynamically?

Comment: @CaptainPlanet Returned by the iframe like the post said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead  of using string concatenation of generate the selector, just use jQuery's `.find()` method:

```
$('.a .b .c').find('.c2, .c3')
```

If you prefer supplying the parent's context, you can also do this:

```
var $parent = $('.a .b .c');
$('.c2, .c3', $parent);
```

This approach will work if you want to bind the click event to the elements without relying on event bubbling:

```
// Solution 1
$('.a .b .c').find('.c2, .c3').click(function() {
    // Handle click event
});

// Solution 2
var $parent = $('.a .b .c');
$('.c2, .c3', $parent).click(function() {
    // Handle click event
});
```

In the event that you need to indeed rely on event bubbling, then you will have to check against the event target's parents:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.c2, .c3', function() {
  // GUARD: Do not proceed if element is not a child of `.a .b .c`
  var $t = $(this);
  if (!$('.a .b .c').find($t).length) {
    return;
  }
  
  // Handle click event
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

```css
.c1, .c2, .c3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: green;
}

.a .b .c .c1,
.foobar .foobaz .foobarbaz .c1, 
.foobar .foobaz .foobarbaz .c2,
.foobar .foobaz .foobarbaz .c3 {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Elements are child of <code>.a .b .c</code>.</p>

<div class="a">
   <div class="b">
     <div class="c">
        <div class="c1">
           C1 (will not fire event)
        </div>
        <div class="c2">
           C2 (will fire event)
        </div>
        <div class="c3">
           C3 (will fire event)
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<hr />

<p>Elements are not child of <code>.a .b .c</code>.</p>

<div class="foobar">
   <div class="foobaz">
     <div class="foobarbaz">
        <div class="c1">
           C1 (will not fire event)
        </div>
        <div class="c2">
           C2 (will not fire event as parents do not match)
        </div>
        <div class="c3">
           C3 (will not fire event as parents do not match)
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sur if this is possible in my case because my event is like that :  `$('body').on('click', '.mySelector', function () { ... });`. I need this cause the div are coming from the iframe and with the solution you propose the events are not biding. But best solution this far

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine Alright. If that's the case, see my updated answer with the code snippet.

Comment: Yeah it's work but in my case I think it's better to keep my big selector than have a specific if. Don't sure but thanks for your help :)

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine Can you define "better"? In one way or another, you are always listening to click event bubbling on the body so performance-wise filtering in the `.on()` method and filtering in the `if` statement makes little difference.

Comment: My initial post was created to have any idea of how to do it. Since It's a work project I prefer code readibility when the performance is not really impacted because other pepoles will work on it after me. Having a big selector with a comment is for me (personal point of view) better than having a if statement who need to be fully understand by other pepoles to update code. (A little hard to explain since I'm french sorry).

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine FYI that's why JS comments are for ;) if the code is not self-explanatory, then adding a comment usually helps. Personally I wouldn't use a big selector string in the `.on(...)` method because it makes it a lot less readable. Also, if you think stuffing it in an `if` statement is too bulky, you can always abstract it to a method that returns a boolean. Just saying.

Comment: yes of couse I will comment my if xP
Just a point of view from me but thanks to drop my personal point of view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to store the common parts:

```
var selector = ".a .b .c ";
$(selector + ".c2, " + selector + ".c3").hide();
```

---

You can also use `.find()`, which looks like it might be closest to your requirement:

```
$(".a .b .c").find(".c1, c2").hide();
```

---

If there's more, you can use `.add()`, something like:

```
var selector = ".a .b .c ";
var parts = [ ".c2", ".c3" ];

var jq = null;
$.each(parts, function(i, val) {
  if (jq == null)
      jq = $(selector + val);
  else
      jq.add(selector + val);
});
jq.hide();
```

Comment: It's a solution, code more readable. Asking myself if it's really better than having a big selector. Code readability or performance ? Will see if someone have a better idea before accepting this :)
Unfortunatly the `.find` method can't be used in my case because it's an click event ( `on('click', 'here my big selector')` )  but It's still a solution for some case

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine If you're not going to rely on event bubbling, you can just chain the collection returned by the selector to `.click(...)`

Comment: @Terry Not sur how to do it but I will look about it. Thanks :)

Comment: You should have mentioned the `.on("click", "selector"` in the question if it's relevant.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use

```
$(".c2,.c3").click(function(e){
//handle click event
});
```

Comment: `.c2 and .c3 class are used on other part of the project so I need to keep the .a .b. .c part.`. Read the entier post :P

Comment: Post some html. The html that you have posted is just a small part. It doesn't mention any other part of html to look for. 

You can have 1 main parent identical and based on that just find the child 

$(".a .c2",".aa c2").click(function(){}); Where a class element has child c2 at any level and aa class element has child c2 at any level. In between a and c2 if there are any element with classes, they can be skipped.

Comment: My post said I have a working selector and want to know if there a way to optimize it because it's a big selector. It's also said that I need to keep The ".a .b .c" part. 
The only real reason I don't post real html is because it's will be harder to understand 100 lines of html than an example and because it's a job projec, I avoid to post client informations on internet if possible